# How to pass multiple parameters to route

Tags: laravel

Hello i have this function called `show` and it has 2 parameters `id` and `options` this is the code from `blade.php` :

```
<a href="{{route('orders.show',$order->id,'1')}}">
<button>Edit</button>
</a>
```

The number one is static but i have another button that has value `2` now this is the code from the controller:

```
public function show($id, $option)
{
    $orders = Order::with('client', 'products')->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
    $clientList = Client::all();
    $productList = Product::all();
    switch ($option)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            return view('orders.edit', compact('orders', 'clientList', 'productList'));
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            return view('orders.show', compact('orders', 'clientList', 'productList'));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But when i execute teh code i get this error:

**Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::show(), 1 passed in /home/user/Desktop/k_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected**

Basically the second argument is not passing i used another method like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('student.detail', ['id' => 5, 'parameter' => 'advanced-web-hindi', 'name' => 'anmol']) }}">Student detail</a>
```

From this page: [Page](https://advancedwebtuts.com/blog-tutorial/how-to-pass-laravel-8-route-multiple-parameters)

While before i passing just one value `$id` and it worked fine but now i need a second parameter to pass.

This is my route definition that just one value passing `$id` works but with two values passing `$id` and `$option` will make error:

```
Route::resource('orders', OrderController::class);
```

Comment: can you show your route definition

Comment: @lagbox yes i will show it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route has 3 parameters `id`, `parameter`, `name`.
You can have two solutions for that.

**1. First Solution**

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/orders/show/{id}', 'OrderController@show')->name('orders.show');
```

**OrderController.php**

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $parameter = $request->input('parameter');
    ....
}
```

**2. Second Solution**

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/orders/show/{id}/{name}/{parameter}', 'OrderController@show')->name('orders.show');
```

**OrderController.php**

```
public function show($id, $name, $parameter)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: i dont understand something that before i was passing only the `$id` and my route is like this `Route::resource('orders', OrderController::class);` no need to declare because the `resource` has it all already by Laravel, so if i insert another parameter why does it fail?

Comment: under this route `Route::resource('orders', OrderController::class);` i have all the options like: `view create, save, update and delete`. All i want is inside the `edit` function to add a second parameter with `switch case`

Comment: First solution is for that, you have to change parameter of ```show($id, $option)```function to ```show(Request $request, $id)```